# how to disable unavilable dates dynamically in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable unaviable dates dynamically how can i do this ?

if i give static value like below its working fine

```
var unavailableDates = ["10-8-2015","24-7-2015","10-7-2015","09-8-2015","09-7-2015","01-12-2015","01-1-2016","11-8-2015"];
```

if i get this value dynamically its not working how can i solve this ?

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/irfanfiddle/JjPrU/849/)

```
var unavailableDates = $('#DesignIdUnavialble').html();

function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#iDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date("7-7-2015"),
        minDate:0,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });

});
```

Whats wrong in my code.Anybody help me ?

Comment: update your html also in fiddle and here in question. `$('#DesignIdUnavialble').html()` will give you a String , while `unavailableDates` expects Array. What is your `.html()` content ? Try using `$('#DesignIdUnavialble').html().split(',')` if it's comma separated dates

Comment: check my updated fiddle :)

Comment: how can do that `$('#DesignIdUnavialble').html().split(',')`  can u give me a demo ? @Amit.rk3

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: sorry i know split i need the expected result @Stormie

Comment: It's like Amit said, it works with the static value because it is an array (what is expected), while the dynamic values do not because they are strings.

What you want to do is either change how you present your dynamic values, you can change your string of dates to an array of substrings using split. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/irfanfiddle/JjPrU/854/)

Just change the date format like m/d/Y

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var Desingndate = $('#DesignIdUnavialble').html();
var splitdate = Desingndate.split(',');
   // console.log(splitdate.length);
    var arrDisabledDates = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < splitdate.length; i++) {
        //console.log(splitdate[i]);    
    arrDisabledDates[new Date(splitdate[i])] = new Date(splitdate[i]);    
    }

     $("#iDate").datepicker({       
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        beforeShowDay: function (dt) {
            var bDisable = arrDisabledDates[dt];
            if (bDisable) return [false, '', ''];
            else return [true, '', ''];
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go , as mentioned in my comment, updated code below.

Updated fiddle - [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JjPrU/855/)

```
var unavailableDates =$('#DesignIdUnavialble').html().replace(/\"/g,'').split(",");
console.log(unavailableDates);
function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}

$(function() {
    $("#iDate").datepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date("3-3-2015"),
        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks amit its working fine in fiddle but not working on my project :) thanks for help once again

Comment: @QuestionUser : it might be because I used different jquery version in fiddle?